# Does the http request header contains "img" only when the client requests a image?

Tags: http, web-applications, header, httprequest, httpresponse

I opened an internet html page, look at the firebug network. A line of the header is:

> Accept    text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Then I opened an internet picture:

> Accept    image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

The value of Accept is different, I think it should return all the acceptable type of the browser every time like this:

> Accept    image/png,image/*,text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5

Cause so I can know weather the server should send a png image even the client requests a html. The question is: if the client do not request a image, can I know weather the client browser can parse a png image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related about how servlets work but how the requests are made to a HTML page. When you fire a request to some URL, let's say https://stackoverflow.com/, you in fact fire more than a single request:

- One GET request for the HTML (text) content of the page
- One GET request per image in the page
- One GET request per resource in the page (CSS, JS, another kind of file used).

This can be easily testable by using a network console. In this case, I use Chrome console to view the requests made when accessing to stackoverflow main page:

[image: GET requests on SO]

---

> if the client do not request a image, can I know weather the client browser can parse a png image?

You can know this by checking the content type of the **response**, not the headers on the request.

You can even see that when performing the request over a png image http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b the server doesn't send any request header related to accept png files:

> **Request Headers**
>
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36

Instead, this is handled in the response headers:

> **Response Headers**
>
> (...) 
> Content-Type:image/png

Comment: Is the Content-Type of that Response Headers you mentioned filled by the server?If i write the jsp to send a respone,should i write:

Comment: Yes, you can write them in the servlet filter.

Comment: The request does not tell me whether the client can accept PNG,how can i decide should the jsp write response.setHeader("Content-Type","image/png") or send another jpg?

Comment: @user3802132 looks like you don't understand the answer. JSP is plain text in HTML format. Images are images and are requested by another GET request on the server which is not the URL of the JSP. I recommend you to test this on any web page online, like stackoverflow or even google.com